# How to find all zeros of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $$f(x) = x^4 - 3x^3 + 2x^2 - 7x - 11. $$ I want to find the roots of $f(x)$.

I know that there are $3$ or $1$ positive roots, $1$ negative root, and $2$ or $0$ imaginary roots but I can't figure out how to find the actual roots, please help...

thank you

Comment: What are you allowed to use? Numerical methods, plots, factoring, closed form solutions...? For example, using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+-+3x%5E3+%2B+2x%5E2+-+7x+-+11+%3D+0)

Comment: Are you sure you've transcribed the function correctly?

Comment: The roots are     $$x_1\approx 3.32901465044,$$
    $$x_2\approx -0.911293966775,$$
    $$x_3\approx 0.291139658168+1.881796991952i,$$
    $$x_4\approx 0.291139658168-1.881796991952i.$$ as found by [this Quartic/Cubic/Quadratic Equation Calculator](http://www.freewebs.com/brianjs/ultimateequationsolver.htm).

Comment: @amWhy this is the correct function that I was given

Comment: @Amzoti I am allowed to use a graphing calculator

Comment: Just checking!: As you can see, your conclusions about the nature of the roots was/is correct: 1 positive, 1 negative real roots, 2 imaginary roots. Using your calculator, be sure to zoom in close enough to catch the "lumpy" behavior near-ish to the origin.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot that you are supposed to graph it, so if that is how you find the real roots, how do you find the imaginary ones? @amWhy

Comment: Becca When you find only two real roots...then you know there are 2 imaginary roots. What those are will not be discernible, but *that* there are will be.

Comment: okay, that is making a lot more sense now, thanks again! @amWhy

Answer (score 1):

The roots are not all that nice...there are two real roots, two imaginary roots:

[From Wolfram Alpha:](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%20-%203x%5E3%20%2b%202x%5E2%20-%207x%20-%2011)

Real roots:

[image]

[image]

Complex roots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: amWhy, was this done using Maple (or a similar tool)? I couldn't think of a way to cleanly analytically tackle this question, even though as a quartic it should be solvable by radicals (which it clearly is, though not particularly nicely). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @AWertheim This was done compliments of Wolfram Alpha. Like you, I tried to do this more cleanly, the failure of which led to testing WA.

Comment: Understandable, that makes sense. Thanks, was just curious if I had missed some clever trick here :)